# How to remove your site in blogger blogspot using robots.txt

Tags: blogger, robots.txt

I have a problem with my blog in blogger.com, I want to delete  the blog and if some one will try to ACCESS the link it will show ERROR 404.
I saw some instructions in the Internet on how to delete the blog but if I  delete it and access the link it will show that I must login to google in order to access it again. I also read in other blogs that you have to use robots.txt

Please help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on how blogger works but I can say for certain that robots.txt isn't going to help. robots.txt is only meant to tell search engines (and the like) what pages to not go to, it doesn't affect users at all. http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Regarding your main question I would guess that it counts as off topic here.

Comment: I see because I saw instructions on how to delete the blog and it is very easy. But i want is to permanently delete this one it will show error 404 web page cant bee found.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you've found out how to delete the blog, then what's the problem? Anything else that can be deleted?

Comment: did you try delete a blogger account? what i am telling is to the delete the whole blooger account for example test123.blogspot.com I want it to directly delete it